# Disable VIm autocommands for specific buffer

Tags: vim, terminal, conque

As a windows user I use conque term as my vim terminal. Is there a way to disable the CursorHoldI and CursorMovedI autocmds when the buffer is a conque term. My vim script skills are basic , I 'm sure there is a line I can add to my vimrc.Thanks

Comment: "As a windows user I use conque term as my vim terminal." What does that even mean?

Comment: Can you give more information on the problem you are trying to solve? Do you mean that you use vim on Windows with the [vim-conque](https://github.com/basepi/vim-conque) plugin?

Comment: Unix users use TMUX and neovim does not support terminal on windows.So those two options are out of the question

 I get this warning when I open conque term and it seems to run slowly. http://tinypic.com/r/rhvmf5/9

Comment: Unix users don't "use tmux" and this seems to be a question for that plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: @romainl not sure why you are going off on a tangent.I use conque_term as my repl.YCM, Vim-surround etc use global autocmds when the cursor is moved, I don't need these when the buffer is conque_term and they slow down the repl.

If I was using Unix I could use tmux as an alternative to switch from vim to a repl.
I simply need a to disable the two autocmds when the buffer is conque_term

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand why you would need to do that, but the way to disable certain autocmds from firing is via the `'eventignore'` option. (Alternatively, you could delete the corresponding autocmds, but that would only work for buffer-scoped ones, not global ones, as you presumably want to keep the autocmds running in non-Conque buffers.)

The thing is, `'eventignore'` is a global setting, so you need another pair of autocmds to turn on / off the option, based on entering / leaving the Conque buffer.

Inside each Conque buffer, run this:

```
:autocmd WinEnter <buffer> set eventignore+=CursorHoldI,CursorMovedI
:autocmd WinLeave <buffer> set eventignore-=CursorHoldI,CursorMovedI
```

Comment: Right thats in line with what I am looking for:
to turn off spelling when the file is markdown I would use :

 autocmd FileType markdown setlocal syntax=off spell

Comment: Is there an equivalent :
autocmd BuffType Conque_term setlocal CursorHoldI,CursorMovedI disabled.
the above didn't work

Comment: I don't use the plugin - check for yourself, e.g. with `:setl buftype?` in the Conque buffer. Also note that the setup in my answer would have to be invoked for _each_ Conque buffer, so you'd have something along `:autocmd FileType ... autocmd WinEnter ...`